# Как протестировать свою программу с помощью библиотеки unittest

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

Хочу протестировать свой код с помощью unittest, но немного не понимаю как это сделать. Во всех статьях разобраны очень легкие примеры(
Вот у меня допустим есть вот такой класс с конструктором и я бы хотел его протестировать:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Класс конечно очень простой и содержательные примеры тестов для него написать трудно. Но для того что есть тесты могут выглядеть так:

```
import unittest

class TestStringMethods(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_has_no_next_node_after_creation(self):
        node = Node('some-data')
        self.assertIsNone(node.next)

    def test_stores_data_after_creation(self):
        node = Node('some-data')
        self.assertEqual(node.data, 'some-data')

    def test_repr_uses_data(self):
        node = Node('some-data')
        self.assertEqual(repr(node), 'some-data')
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!